# SVG css transition property

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

Can I set SVG elements' x or y attributes as transition property? If not, what are the  alternative solutions to position change transition?

```
svg text { transition: x 1s ease-in; }
```

x above is the transition property I want to set.

Comment: you want svg element to animate?

Comment: You can't CSS animate SVG text x or y. They are not mapped CSS properties.

Comment: @iamjcc as Rob said you cannot animate text, I have answered animated svg below let me know if that helps if not I will take that answer out.

Comment: @iamjcc, thanks for the explanation,  I will take out my answer.